# Android AIDE lambdas

Tags: java, android, lambda

I like programming apps on my Android tablet, using the AIDE development environment (which recently supports Java 7).

Would it now be possible to use Java 8 lambda expressions?
... even by somehow faking it?

(I ask because I use the TotallyLazy libraries, which would really benefit from the lambda syntax.)

Comment: By faking it, I mean like the way Android Studio does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AIDE developer here] AIDEs code analysis engine and Java compiler do not support lambda expressions at this time. Since the code analysis engine (used for code completion, error checking and refactoring) does not support it and the Java compiler is not pluggable there is no way of faking it with something like retrolambda either.

Comment: This article claims it is possible, though it may be a mistake: http://zserge.com/blog/android-lambda.html

Comment: Retrolambda is not supported in AIDE.

Comment: By the way, somewhat related to this, AIDE seems to have problems compiling projects using the Retrofit 2 library (often used in conjunction with Retrolambda). It seems to strip the method annotations needed by Retrofit, causing a runtime exception. The same project compiles and runs fine on Android Studio. In fact, Android Studio managed to run AIDE's own project

Answer (score 0):

The Java syntax for AIDE is only compatible with JDK5